# getting Syntax error ERROR 1064 (42000) while migrating AWS RDS(MYSQL) to GCP Cloud SQL(MYSQL)

Tags: database, amazon-rds, database-migration, google-cloud-sql

I want to migrate RDS MYSQL database(Size 150GB) to Cloud SQL database. For this i am using Database migration Service of GCP. but while migrating, i am getting syntax errors and if i am trying to do it manual it is working fine.

Errors:
Attempt 1/2: import failed with non-retriable error: error during mysqldump: import err = generic::failed_precondition: error:
exit status 1
stdout(capped at 100k bytes):

stderr:
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 35830: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:au' at line 1, mysqldump err = signal: killed, stderr =

Migration job aws-to-gcp-migration-job status changed from RUNNING, WAITING_FOR_SOURCE_WRITES_TO_STOP to FAILED, WAITING_FOR_SOURCE_WRITES_TO_STOP.
Failure due to the following error:
error code: 0,
error message: Attempt 1/2: import failed with non-retriable error: error during mysqldump: import err = generic::failed_precondition: error:
exit status 1
stdout(capped at 100k bytes):

stderr:
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 49419: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''{"checkin":"2020-12-31 15:43' at line 1, mysqldump err = signal: killed, stderr =

"Migration job aws-to-gcp-sqldb-migration status changed from RUNNING, WAITING_FOR_SOURCE_WRITES_TO_STOP to FAILED, WAITING_FOR_SOURCE_WRITES_TO_STOP.\nFailure due to the following error:\n error code: 0,\n error message: Attempt 1/2: import failed with non-retriable error: error during mysqldump: import err = generic::failed_precondition: error:\nexit status 1\nstdout(capped at 100k bytes):\n\nstderr:\nERROR 1064 (42000) at line 47113: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''{\"n_id\":940203,\"name\":\"Abhishek\",\"status\":\"Timeout\",\"vuid\":\"28581d' at line 1, mysqldump err = signal: killed, stderr ="

**these are different syntax errors, getting while trying again and again, every time getting different syntax error.**

What should i do, please suggest.

i used database migration service of gcp but it did not work and when taking manual dump, and importing into cloud sql getting: error: exit status 1 stdout(capped at 100k bytes): stderr: ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 18: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation.